# check only the checkbox inside the class jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have multiple div's with same class and each dev has some input box. Whenever I change the value in input box, inside the div all the input boxes should the updated values in that particular div only not all the div's

```
<div class="select-guest__info table-responsive ">
  
      <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="2" />
      <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="2" />
      <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="2" />


</div>
<div class="select-guest__info table-responsive ">
  
      <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="1" />
      <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="1" />
      <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="1" />


</div>
```

I tried with

```
 $('.select-guest__info .js-qty').each(function () {
  $(this).val(val);
 });
```

but all the input boxes are updating with the latest value.How Can I update only the inputboxes which are inside the div.

Regards,
Sree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `siblings()` to target all siblings of inputs and change value there.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".js-qty").change(function() {
  $(this).siblings().val($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-guest__info table-responsive ">
  <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="2" />
  <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="2" />
  <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="select-guest__info table-responsive ">
  <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="1" />
  <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="1" />
  <input class="js-qty" type="number" value="1" />
</div>
```